# How to submit multiple jquery posts to a page one after another if database updates successfully?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to send multiple $.post to a single page. I need each to post to a page that updates a database then post the next one until they are done. This is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#action").change(function(){
var selectVal = $('#action :selected').val();
if(selectVal == "list-all"){

    $(".prelistCheckbox:checked").each(function(index) {
        var theValue = $(this).val();
        console.log('Values to be passed: ' + theValue);
        var form = $('form[id=' + theValue + ']');
        console.log(form.serialize());
//          $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(data) {
        $.post('jqueryPost.php', form.serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#results').text(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

}
});
});
```

I'm really not sure how to make it make it do this. The forms are generated from rows of a database with a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deferred objects will help you here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#action").change(function(){
        var selectVal = $('#action :selected').val();
        if(selectVal == "list-all"){

            //define a variable where we will store deferred objects
            var def = true;

            $(".prelistCheckbox:checked").each(function(index) {
                var theValue = $(this).val();
                console.log('Values to be passed: ' + theValue);
                var form = $('form[id=' + theValue + ']');
                console.log(form.serialize());

                var postResult = $.Deferred();

                //.when take a deferred object as a param. 
                // if we pass not a deferred object .when treats it as resolved.
                // as our initial value of def=true, the first .when starts immediately
                $.when(def).then(function(){
                    $.post('jqueryPost.php', form.serialize(), function(data) {
                        $('#results').text(data);
                        console.log(data);
                    }).done(function(){
                        //the chain will fail after the first failed post request
                        //if you want all the requests to complete in any case change the above .done to .always
                        post.resolve();
                    });
                });

                // now we reassign def with th deferred object for the next post request
                def = postResult;
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Simply amazing, thank you so very much. I can't thank you enough. I'm off to read more on deferred objects.